# Why joining tables in this order returns nothing?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables A and B that I am trying to join on a particular column.

While the column of A contains NULLs besides values, the column of B does not contain any NULLs.

When I try to join A and B in the following way

```
SELECT *
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.XXX = B.XXX;
```

returns nothing, but doing

```
SELECT *
FROM B INNER JOIN A ON B.XXX = A.XXX;
```

returns the results I expected.

Why is this happening?

*Simplified table structure:*

```
Table A:   TableB:
  XXX        XXX
 -----      ------
  111        111
  222        222
  333        222
  NULL       333
  444        444
   :          :
```

Comment: They *should* return identical results - are you able to create an [mcve] that demonstrates this (i.e. some actual `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements that we can then use these queries against and that demonstrate the problem?)

Comment: Can you share the table structure and data details , that would help . If not the production data sample data would do

Comment: Check for hidden characters such as tabs in your fields, your query should run fine as you wrote it above.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange as the order of `JOIN` generally won't matter but you can try checking for `NULL` on join condition like

```
 FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.XXX = B.XXX
 OR A.XXX IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test data.

```
SQL> select * from a;

       XXX COL2
---------- ---------
           22-MAR-17
       111 22-MAR-17
       222 22-MAR-17
       333 22-MAR-17
       444 22-MAR-17

SQL> select * from b;

       XXX       COL1
---------- ----------
       555        678
       444        567
       333        456
       222        345
       222        234
       111        123

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

As we would expect, join order has no difference on the result set. In both cases we get one row for every match on A.XXX and B.XXX:

```
SQL> select a.*, b.*
  2  from a inner join b 
  3       on a.xxx = b.xxx
  4  /

       XXX COL2             XXX       COL1
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
       444 22-MAR-17        333        567
       333 22-MAR-17        333        456
       222 22-MAR-17        222        345
       222 22-MAR-17        222        234
       111 22-MAR-17        111        123

6 rows selected.

SQL> select a.*, b.*
  2  from b inner join a
  3      on b.xxx = a.xxx
  4  /

       XXX COL2             XXX       COL1
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
       444 22-MAR-17        333        567
       333 22-MAR-17        333        456
       222 22-MAR-17        222        345
       222 22-MAR-17        222        234
       111 22-MAR-17        111        123

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So you are doing something different from what you've posted here, or there's some peculiarity in your data which you're not showing us.

Comment: ummm, I will look into it.